# NO OBTENGO NINGUN REGISTRO DE MYSQL EN PHP

Tags: php, mysql, pdo

he estado un tiempo trabajando con php e intentando hacer funcionar el codigo MYSQL que está dentro de PHP, estoy trabajando con PDO pero al momento en que quiero obtener los registros de mi base de datos y pongo el print_r($variable); me muestra un array vacio.

```
<?php 

function conexion(){
    try {
        $conexion = new PDO('mysql:localhost;dbname=u766373438','u766373438user', '1987');
        return $conexion;
    } catch(PDOException $e) {
        return false;
    }
}

$sql = conexion();

$table = $sql->prepare('SELECT * FROM ejemplo');
$table->execute();
$resultado = $table->fetchAll();

print_r($resultado);
```

?>

[image: Lo que me muestra el print_r]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

De acuerdo a la documentación oficial tu sintaxis de conexión le falta algunos argumentos.

http://php.net/manual/es/pdo.connections.php

Tu versión

```
$conexion = new PDO('mysql:localhost;dbname=u766373438','u766373438user', '1987');
```

Versión de la documentación , te falto definir la palabra host.

```
$conexion = new PDO('mysql:host=localhost;dbname=u766373438', 'u766373438user', '1987');
```

Answer (score 0):

lo que has puesto esta bien, es mas esta linea tambien procede.

```
 $conexion = new PDO('mysql:localhost;dbname=u766373438','u766373438user', '1987');
```

tu error en en usar el mismo nombre de tu funcion a mi me corrio el codigo ok

```
<?php 
function conexion(){
    try {
        $db = new PDO('mysql:localhost;dbname=u766373438','u766373438user', '1987');        
        return $db;
    } catch(PDOException $e) {
        return false;
    }
}

$sql = conexion();
$table = $sql->prepare('SELECT * FROM ejemplo');
$table->execute();
$resultado = $table->fetchAll();
print_r($resultado);
?>
```

como siempre realizo mis pruebas

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]